# Ember JS: Nested api routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I need to perform a GET operation to the following HTTP end point:

```
/api/v1/users/security_questions.json?memberID=1234
```

I've been told that Ember JS does not support a nested endpoint like users/security_questions and rather I would need to do:

```
/api/v1/security_questions.json?memberID=1234
```

Is nested API routes supported? If so, how do I implement it in my Model?

Comment: You can if you include a `security_questions` link in your `users` payload. Did you consider a plain AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported out-of-the-box, however it's pretty easy to add it in. You'll need to override the `pathForType` method in your RESTAdapter

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  pathForType: function(type) {

    // Assuming your model name is security_question
    if (type === 'security_question' ) {

      // If it's a security question, set this as the path
      return 'users/security_questions.json';

    } else {

      // If not, call super to pluralize the model name as normal
      return this._super(type);

    }

  }

});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. For customizing any endpoint, you have to write an adapter for that model.
2. There are multiple hooks available in an adapter.

   - `host` - variable, gets prefixed in the calls
   - `pathForType(modelName)` : Can be used for customizing the path for a given type
   - `buildURL (modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query)` : Offers more customization

You can refer [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.BuildURLMixin.html#method_buildURL) in Ember Guides.